# Wtforms: What is the difference between validators=[DataRequired()] and [validator.DataRequired()]?

Tags: flask, wtforms

validators = [DataRequired()] seems to work while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference just you are doing a typo:

```
[validator.DataRequired()]
```

should be:

```
[validators.DataRequired()]
```